# How to get currently selected cell or range in Excel document using OpenXML library and C#

Tags: c#, excel-2007, openxml

I am trying to get currently selected cell or range of cells for changing or editing value or style, but I don't like to use *Interop* libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Selection does not get saved in the xlsx. I have saved 2 blank workbooks, with different selection and then compared recursively the extracted file contents of the two zip packages. Only difference is `dcterms:modified` node in `docProps\core.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

In each sheet,

The SheetView element has active cells, like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<worksheet xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" mc:Ignorable="x14ac" xmlns:x14ac="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/ac">
  <dimension ref="A1:B8"/>
  <sheetViews>
    <sheetView tabSelected="1" workbookViewId="0">
      <selection activeCell="A2" sqref="A2:B3"/>
    </sheetView>
  </sheetViews>
```

The OpenXML class that gets you this is
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.selection.activecell(v=office.14).aspx